# Send button not working of custom keyboard in android in case of instagram

Tags: android, custom-keyboard

I have created a custom keyboard which is working fine so far , but i am getting an issue , when i try to send message in Instagram app (or any other app) , action enter didn't work.

My code :

```
private void sendKey(int keyCode) {
    switch (keyCode) {
        case '\n':
            keyDownUp(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER);
            break;
        default:
            if (keyCode >= '0' && keyCode <= '9') {
                keyDownUp(keyCode - '0' + KeyEvent.KEYCODE_0);
            } else {
      this.mInputConnection.commitText(String.valueOf((char) keyCode), 1);
                removeSuggestionFromTextView();
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please specify what `not working` means in terms of errors, unexpected result etc.

Comment: have u debugged it? does it goes into the '\n' case? maybe its not the right case to use for the enter key..try with case 13:

https://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

Comment: getCurrentInputEditorInfo() from this method I always get actionId = 0 instead of 4 in case of imeOption send.